# Question on polar coordinates and cartesian coordinates

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know the conversion between polar coordinates and cartesian coordinates. Nevertheless, I cannot understand why $r=2a\cos\theta$ represents a circle of radius $a$ and center $(a,0)$.
Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 1):

The graph hopefully makes clear angle subtended at origin is half that at center inside semi-circle and placed that way.

$ r = 2 a \cos \theta $

where the radius vector $r$ is a projection of diameter $ 2 a. $

The polar equation of all circles through the origin, rotated by $\alpha $ is:

$ r = 2 a \cos (\theta + \alpha) $

[image: PolarEqun CircleThrough Origin]

Answer (score 0):

A way to convince yourself is to revert to Cartesian coordinates:

$$r=2a\cos\theta$$
becomes
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=2a\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},$$
$$x^2+y^2-2ax=0,$$
$$(x-a)^2+y^2=a^2.$$

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you draw out the graph with the circle because that's how I understand it. You could try and put it a few values for $\theta$ to see how the shape of the circle comes out.